# I need to implement flutter eventChannel in Objective-C class

Tags: swift, objective-c, flutter

My project mixes Objective-C and Swift
I need to implement flutter eventChannel in Objective-C class
how should I do it?

- I try to add a callback in Objective-C and return the result to the eventChannel in   AppDelegate.swift. But it seems something is wrong... I am not familiar with Objectiv-C, who can help me
- myController.h

```
typedef void(^NfcBlock)(bool isSuccess); // the nfc and ble service is from a static library.
typedef void(^BleBlock)(bool isSuccess); // i need return connect result to flutter view.
@interface MyController : NSObject<NfcDelegate, BleServiceDelegate,CBCentralManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) BlePassService *blePassService;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NfcPassService *nfcService;
@property (nonatomic,strong) MobilePass *mobilePass;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NfcBlock nfcBlock;
@property (nonatomic,strong) BleBlock bleBlock;
```

- AppDelegate.swift

```
 func nfcCallback(isSuccess:Bool){
// add event sink
}

  case CallMethod.initState:
               if passKit == nil { return }
                passKit.initial()
                passKit.setNfcBlock(nfcCallback)
                result(String("success"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Instead of methodChannel I should use FlutterBasicMessageChannel . It can communicate bidirectionally

```
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
API_AVAILABLE(ios(14.0))
@interface PassKit : NSObject<NfcDelegate, BleServiceDelegate,CBCentralManagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) FlutterBasicMessageChannel *msgChannel;
```

.m File

```
- (void)sendData:(NSString *)data{
    if(_msgChannel==nil) {
         [_msgChannel sendMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"error"]];
        return;
    };

    [_msgChannel sendMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data]];
}
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
let twoWayMethodChannel = FlutterBasicMessageChannel(name: ChannelName.twoWayName, binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger);

passKit.setChannel(twoWayMethodChannel)
```